# electron-builder, in windows ,how to config that can exit the installation process?

Tags: electron, electron-builder

I am using electron-builder's NSIS key to control my app's installation behavior.

I hope users can terminate the installation during the installation process.

But once the installation starts, I cannot stop it, the cancel button is disabled.

[image]

I want to know how do I need to configure to make the buttons available?

below is my configuration:

```
{
    "nsis": {
      "oneClick": false,
      "perMachine": true,
      "allowToChangeInstallationDirectory": true
    }
}
```

Thank you.